# SQL Transport error timeout when creating an index

Tags: indexing, timeout, azure-sql-database, ssms

I'm getting a transport error when I try to create an index. These are very large tables and I would expect the index to take a long time however I thought running the query from SSMS had no timeout and would run until completed.

CREATE INDEX [IDX_Index1_field1_field2_field3] ON [Database1].[dbo].[Table1] ([field1], [field2], [field3]) INCLUDE ([Include1], [Include2], [Include3], [Include4], [Include5], [TypeId6], [Include7], [Include8], [Include9], [Include10], [Include11], [Include12])

The error is this: http://screencast.com/t/fyi1yyYg6

Msg 10054, Level 20, State 0, Line 0
A transport-level error has occurred when receiving results from the server. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 0 - An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.)

Is there anything I can do to prevent this Transport error from killing the index query? This is a SQL Azure DB btw.

Thank for any help in advance.